# How to get log and show it on GUI from multiprocessing work?

Tags: pyqt5, python-multiprocessing, python-logging

I try to get logs from multiprocessing work and show them on GUI.
Based on this [document](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#a-qt-gui-for-logging)

gui.py:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import logging
from log_test import main
Signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal
Slot = QtCore.pyqtSlot


class Signaller(QtCore.QObject):
    signal = Signal(str, logging.LogRecord)


class QtHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, slotfunc, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.signaller = Signaller()
        self.signaller.signal.connect(slotfunc)

    def emit(self, record):
        s = self.format(record)
        self.signaller.signal.emit(s, record)


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = Signal()

    @Slot()
    def start(self):
        main()
        self.finished.emit()


class Ui_Dialog(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.setEnabled(True)
        Dialog.resize(530, 440)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.button.setText("start working")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.logWidget = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.logWidget.setReadOnly(True)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.logWidget)

        self.handler = QtHandler(self.update_log_gui)
        logging.getLogger('log').addHandler(self.handler)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.start_work)

    @Slot(str, logging.LogRecord)
    def update_log_gui(self, status, record):
        self.logWidget.appendPlainText(status)

    def config_thread(self):
        self.worker_thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.worker_thread.setObjectName('WorkerThread')
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
        self.worker_thread.started.connect(self.worker.start)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker_thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.worker_thread.finished.connect(self.worker_thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker_thread.finished.connect(lambda: self.button.setEnabled(True))
        pass

    def start_work(self):
        self.config_thread()
        self.worker_thread.start()
        self.button.setEnabled(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    QtCore.QThread.currentThread().setObjectName('MainThread')
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

log_test.py (where multiprocessing work happens)

```py
import logging
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


def f(name):
    logger = logging.getLogger('log.' + name)
    logger.error('hello there 1')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    logger.error('hello there 2')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    logger.error('hello there 3')
    time.sleep(0.5)


def main():
    with Pool(5) as p:
        p.map(f, ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'])
```

At first time, I thought working in single thread causing the problem. So I added QThread to this.

Later I discovered in debug, it seems to `QtHandler.emit()` works fine at receiving log messages. But the connected slot function, `update_log_gui()` does not work somehow.

Comment: It isn't working because the processes created by the `Pool` class no longer share a root logger with your `QtHandler` class.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. In future, if you need to make amendments, edit the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75445026/984421) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.

@Alexander was right. Indeed my `QtHandler` has a problem when multiprocessing but I don't know exactly why. Rather, you wanna implement `QueueHandler`. An example in [this article](https://wikidocs.net/87141) (Written in Korean) helped me.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import logging
import multiprocessing
from log_test import main
Signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal
Slot = QtCore.pyqtSlot
QThread = QtCore.QThread


class Signaller(QtCore.QObject):
    signal = Signal(logging.LogRecord)


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = Signal()

    def __init__(self, q):
        super().__init__()
        self.q = q

    @Slot()
    def start(self):
        main(self.q)
        self.finished.emit()


class Consumer(QThread):
    popped = Signaller()

    def __init__(self, q):
        super().__init__()
        self.q = q
        self.setObjectName('ConsumerThread')

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if not self.q.empty():
                record = self.q.get()
                self.popped.signal.emit(record)


class Ui_Dialog(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__()
        self.app = app

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.setEnabled(True)
        Dialog.resize(530, 440)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.button.setText("start working")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.logWidget = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.logWidget.setReadOnly(True)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.logWidget)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.start_work)

        self.q = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
        self.consumer = Consumer(self.q)
        self.consumer.popped.signal.connect(self.update_log_gui)
        self.consumer.start()

        app.aboutToQuit.connect(self.shutdown_consumer)


    @Slot(logging.LogRecord)
    def update_log_gui(self, record):
        self.logWidget.appendPlainText(str(record.msg))

    def config_thread(self):
        self.worker_thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.worker_thread.setObjectName('WorkerThread')
        self.worker = Worker(self.q)
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
        self.worker_thread.started.connect(self.worker.start)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker_thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.worker_thread.finished.connect(self.worker_thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker_thread.finished.connect(lambda: self.button.setEnabled(True))

    def start_work(self):
        self.config_thread()
        self.worker_thread.start()
        self.button.setEnabled(False)

    def shutdown_consumer(self):
        if self.consumer.isRunning():
            self.consumer.requestInterruption()
            self.consumer.quit()
            self.consumer.wait()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    QtCore.QThread.currentThread().setObjectName('MainThread')
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog(app)
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```